# Windows 8.1 Universal App Multitasking Foreground-Background Cycle

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a way to know if the app is sent to background or brought to foreground. I don't mean Suspended and Resuming events.

For example, user leaves the app to check something on Facebook app for a min. And then return to back to my app. So suspention doesn't take effect on this scenario. Then how to know user is back to the app on app.cs level?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx):

> Your app doesn't receive an activation event when app visibility changes, because the app is still running. Windows simply switches to and from the app as necessary. If your app needs to do something when the user switches away and back, it can handle the [visibilitychange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441213.aspx) event (for HTML) or [Window.VisibilityChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged.aspx) event (for XAML).

Comment: i knew this, but i didn't try because saw someone complaining about this firing everytime a messagedialog comes on screen too.. is this wrong?

Comment: @garenyondem yes, it fires like CRAZY, every time something happens, but it appears to be the only way. But you should be able to evaluate the sender and args to respond only to the correct behavior.